# Get rid of extra blank space on right with horizontal bar?

Tags: css, alignment, padding, margin

So here is the website: [a link](http://dropbuckets.com)

When you make your screen smaller and scroll horizontally... you will see my issue where everything within the "wrapper" gets cut off and then there is a whole bunch of extra blank space on the right... I'm pretty sure it's in the wrapper, but I'm not sure how to get this wrapper to stay still and not get cut off when the screen is minimized.

ANy help on this issue would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your code for the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to place your wave background image inside the footer class instead in an ul tag. Your footer id is already set to be 100% witdh so it should fill out the complete bottom of the page.

```
#footer {
    height:275px;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:0;
    background: #000 url(http://dropbuckets.com/wp-content/themes/Freshman%20101/images/waves.png) repeat-x 0 top; 
}
```

Make sure the white in your wave png is not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `min-width` on your `body` to that of the largest element on your page. In this case `#access` was 940px:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1F1F1;
    min-width: 940px; /* add this */
}
```